# 90 degree down angled USB connector for iphone 4s

Tags: usb

Anyone know of supplier of such a cable?  I have very restricted space at rear of car headunit to fit the USB connector - hence I need a down angled USB plug with a 30 pin connectoe at other end.   Apple doe not seem to manufacture them.  I want to buy one that is supported by Apple- ie they cannot "disable" it because the manufacturer is not licenced.

Comment: I don't think Apple can disable a cable because it's not "licensed".

Comment: @IronCraftMan That's not accurate. Right now it just displays a warning message but they could disable it if they so chose. The whole point of the [MFi program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFi_Program) is that licensed cables have a chip in them that identifies them as such.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered a 90 degree USB adapter instead of a specialized dock/30-pin cable?  I'm using this right angle adapter with my Alpine head unit and a 10' lightning cable and have no issues with my iPhone 6 or 7 plus.

[Right angle USB 3.0 adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009LJCABS)

If you absolutely need it to come out of the head unit and straight down then you should be able to use one of these with similar results.

[L Shape USB 3.0 adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01G8H7I44)

The "accessory not supported" messages usually are a result of an aftermarket cable that isn't manufactured within the guidelines of the [Apple MFi program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MFi_Program).  This pertains more to the lightning or dock connector end rather than the USB connection end of the cable.  Because of that you should be able to use just about any USB adapter to meet your needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Many thanks - especially to Mr Rabbit,  The professional auto electrician fitter used a non-IOS USB extension cable, and I wondered if that was why the headunit did not recognise the iphone....I read somewhere that IOS USB uses 2amps whereas non-IOS uses less (400milliamps??).....is this a fallacy?  I simply want to get bits that are likely to work...IOS or otherwise.  Any informed views re ampage?